# how do i remove this error in mutate command in R?

Tags: r

```r
data1m %>% mutate(data1m,TP = ThGA+NuGA+HyGA) %>%  group_by(Date) %>% summarise(ATP = sum(TP)) %>%
   filter(Date > "2017-09-30") %>% mutate(year = year(Date)) %>% 
   ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = ATP))+geom_line(color = "blue")+theme_classic()+
   geom_smooth(method = "lm",se = 0, linetype = "dashed", color = "red")
```

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `TP`.
> x non-numeric argument to binary operator
> i Input `TP` is `ThGA + NuGA + HyGA`.
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Help us help you: Provide a [mcve]. In particular, you should [edit] your question to include the output of the R command `dput(data1m)`

Answer (score 2):

1. You should remove "data1m" from the `mutate` argument;
2. You can add `dplyr::` to `mutate` in case it conflicts with a function with the same name but from another package.

try:

```
    data1m %>% dplyr::mutate(TP = ThGA+NuGA+HyGA)
```